# Troubleshooting 'list index out of range' error in Keras flow_from_dataframe with TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

In the original kaggle notebook, This code runs but the same code doesn't run on my kaggle notebook

I tried to run this getting error of list out of range. I defined this `flow_from_dataframe` to work smoothly instead of using the default one in keras
in the original it works not in mine.

```py
def flow_from_dataframe(img_data_gen, in_df, path_col, y_col, **dflow_args):
    if(path_col is not None):
    
        base_dir = os.path.dirname(in_df[path_col].values[0])
        print('## Ignore next message from keras, values are replaced anyways')
        df_gen = img_data_gen.flow_from_directory(base_dir, 
                                     class_mode = 'sparse',
                                    **dflow_args)
        df_gen.filenames = in_df[path_col].values
        df_gen.classes = np.stack(in_df[y_col].values)
        df_gen.samples = in_df.shape[0]
        df_gen.n = in_df.shape[0]
        df_gen._set_index_array()
        df_gen.directory = '' # since we have the full path
        print('Reinserting dataframe: {} images'.format(in_df.shape[0]))
    return df_gen
image_size = (128, 128) # image re-sizing target
train_gen = keras.flow_from_dataframe(data_gen, train_set, path_col = 'full_path', y_col = 'target_vector', target_size = image_size, color_mode = 'grayscale', batch_size = 32)
valid_gen = keras.flow_from_dataframe(data_gen, test_set, path_col = 'full_path', y_col = 'target_vector', target_size = image_size, color_mode = 'grayscale', batch_size = 128)

# define test sets
test_X, test_Y = next(keras.flow_from_dataframe(data_gen, test_set, path_col = 'full_path', y_col = 'target_vector', target_size = image_size, color_mode = 'grayscale', 
                                          batch_size = 2048))
```

This is my code and below is error. In the original kaggle notebook it runs perfectly. When I wrote the same Python code in my kaggle notebook, this gives my index error. Please help me.

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[17], line 10
      7 valid_gen = flow_from_dataframe(data_gen, test_set, path_col = 'full_path', y_col = 'target_vector', target_size = image_size, color_mode = 'grayscale', batch_size = 128)
      9 # define test sets
---> 10 test_X, test_Y = next(flow_from_dataframe(data_gen, test_set, path_col = 'full_path', y_col = 'target_vector', target_size = image_size, color_mode = 'grayscale', 
     11                                           batch_size = 2048))

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/preprocessing/image.py:156, in Iterator.__next__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    155 def __next__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 156     return self.next(*args, **kwargs)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/preprocessing/image.py:168, in Iterator.next(self)
    165     index_array = next(self.index_generator)
    166 # The transformation of images is not under thread lock
    167 # so it can be done in parallel
--> 168 return self._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index_array)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/preprocessing/image.py:371, in BatchFromFilesMixin._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(self, index_array)
    368 filepaths = self.filepaths
    369 for i, j in enumerate(index_array):
    370     img = image_utils.load_img(
--> 371         filepaths[j],
    372         color_mode=self.color_mode,
    373         target_size=self.target_size,
    374         interpolation=self.interpolation,
    375         keep_aspect_ratio=self.keep_aspect_ratio,
    376     )
    377     x = image_utils.img_to_array(img, data_format=self.data_format)
    378     # Pillow images should be closed after `load_img`,
    379     # but not PIL images.

IndexError: list index out of range
```